# Display contents based on CSS

Tags: css

This may be a beginner question concerning CSS.

Is it possible to decide what to to print (dispay) using CSS and media queries?

Say for example if my window (or device screen) is smaller than 500 pixels then dispay "Hello!" otherwise dispay "Guten Tag!"

What I have found shows how to decide some display attribute (color or ...), never the contents itself.

Comment: You'd need to have to elements, one for screen bigger than 500 and one for less than 500. Then use media queries to show/hide one on them

Comment: You just change the `display` setting in your CSS for 2 different elements, and use media queries to toggle between `display:none` and `display:block`

Comment: It seems that those elements are about the way to display, not about the contents. Am I wrong? I hope I am.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to have two elements, one for screen bigger than 500 and one for less than 500. Then use media queries to show/hide one on them
DEMO: http://jsbin.com/pizosehire/edit?output

**HTML**

```
<div class="large">Hello</div>
<div class="small">Guten Tag</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.small {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .large {
    display: none;
  }
  .small {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `pseudo-element` with [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/content):

```css
p::before{ content: 'foo' }

@media (max-width: 500px){
   p::before{ content: 'bar' }
}
```

```html
<p></p>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/44kjvvjd/)

Comment: Yep, use this trick to switch between menu icons on mobile and their longer worded counterparts on desktop. Great way to do it :)

Comment: Couldn't agree more :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to work with media-queries.

You can change your css to something like this

```
@media (max-width: 500px){
   #mydiv{ background: url('img-sx.img') }
}
@media (min-width: 501px){
   #mydiv{ background: url('img-s.img') }
}
```